# Метод как снять ограничения с пользователя в Телеграмм

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Python Aiogram есть метод await bot.restrict_chat_member(...) для бота, он вводит ограничения у пользователей в группе в Телеграмм.

Подскажите пожалуйста обратный метод в библиотеке Aiogram, как при помощи бота снять ограничения. Не могу найти. Пример кода пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Передайте значение `True` для всех [разрешений](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/ChatPermissions#pyrogram.types.ChatPermissions), чтобы снять ограничения с пользователя.